# Hide/Show jcf Select (dropdown) from jquery

Tags: jquery, css

My select dropdown

```
<select class="model" id="model" name="model" style="display:none;">
    <option value="model1">Model1</option>
    <option value="model2">Model2</option>
    <option value="model3">Model3</option>
    <option value="model4">Model4</option>
</select>
```

I am using jcf plugin for select. Refrence https://www.psd2html.com/js-custom-forms/

Now i want to display my dropdown from jquery.
`jQuery("select[name='model']").show();`

But this is not working anymore.How can i change `display:none` to `display:block` ?

Comment: use id since you have it `$("#model").show();`

Comment: `jQuery("select[name='model']").show();` should work. any errors in console?

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery("select[name='model']").css('display', 'block');`

Comment: Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/5h6vce6r/ problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: My code is actually working before i used jcf plugin. But not after i used jcf plugin for select. That is main problem.

Comment: @caramba please check https://jsfiddle.net/5h6vce6r/4/. That's what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because jcf plugin hides native element and create equivalent custom element as next sibling to it. In this case, the select element is hidden by default and hence jcf do not create equivalent element out of it.

Hence you need to show the select element first and then initialize jcf plugin:

```
$("#model").css('display','block');
jcf.replaceAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change display:none to display:block by using this code:

```
$("#model").css('display','block');
```

Comment: this will work for normal case if i am not using jcf plugin